# Login with two different roles

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an `admin` which can create several recordings in the form `Members`.

In the table `Members`, there are 2 fields `user_id` and `team_id`.

Here is an example below:

[image]

Now, my problem is that I want to log  for example with the user `jeremy@gmail.com`.

I have to see only my informations.
Here is an example:

[image]

### DataBase:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

I'm trying to understand the syntax to do?

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {   

        $user = $request->user();
        $members = Member::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
         $query->where('id???', $user->email); ????
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name??', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
         })->with('team:id,name') 
        ->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.members.index', compact('members'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));

    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What are you trying? The quesiton isnt very clear.

Comment: @Collin: when I log in with the user 'jeremy@gmail.com' I do not get the information from the user.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificaiton, you can just use auth()->user to get the information of the current user. Then compact that data with the view